# PHP - Loopless way to split a string into a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, string, scripting

How do I split a string into a multidimensional array in PHP without loops?

My string is in the format `"A,5|B,3|C,8"`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to do it without loops?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without **you** actually doing the looping part, something based on [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/array_map) + [`explode`](http://www.php.net/explode) should do the trick ; for instance, considering you are using PHP 5.3 :

```
$str = "A,5|B,3|C,8";

$a = array_map(
    function ($substr) {
        return explode(',', $substr);
    }, 
    explode('|', $str)
);
var_dump($a);
```

Will get you :

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string 'A' (length=1)
      1 => string '5' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string 'B' (length=1)
      1 => string '3' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array
      0 => string 'C' (length=1)
      1 => string '8' (length=1)
```

Of course, this portion of code could be re-written to not use a lambda-function, and work with PHP < 5.3 -- but not as fun ^^

Still, I presume `array_map` will loop over each element of the array returned by `explode`... So, even if the loop is not in your code, there will still be one...

Answer (score 3):

Without loops at all? Can't be done. Without you having to write the loop? Explode or one of the regex "split" methods.

Comment: Unless of course the multidimensional arrays are always of the same size, but thats not usually a good assumption....

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match_all("~([^|,]+),([^|,]+)~", $str, $m);
$result = array_combine($m[1], $m[2]);
```

this returns an array like array('A' => 5, 'B' => 3 etc

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether array_walk() counts as a loop...

```
<?php

class Splitter {  
  function __construct($text){
    $this->items = array();
    array_walk(explode('|', $text), array($this, 'split'));
  }

  function split($input){
    $this->items[] = explode(',', $input);
  }
}

$s = new Splitter("A,5|B,3|C,8");
print_r($s->items);
```

Answer (score -1):

If your data is huge this could get heavy but here's one solution:

```
<?php
$data = "A,5|B,3|C,8";
$search = array("|",",");
$replace = array("&","=");
$array = parse_str(str_replace($search, $replace, $data));
?>
```

Would result into something like this:

```
$array = array(
  A => 5,
  B => 3,
  C => 8,
);
```

Comment: [`Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: parse_str() expects exactly 2 arguments, 1 given`](https://3v4l.org/QG4b5)

Comment: Your assumed output is not a multidimensional array.