# how to write a java pattern in this format: any characters (int,int) (int,int) number number any number of (int,int,int)

Tags: java, regex

For example

```
Maze0.bmp (0,0) (319,239) 65 120
Maze0.bmp (0,0) (319,239) 65 120 (254,243,90)  
Maze0.bmp (0,0) (319,239) 65 120 (254,243,90) (0,0,0)
Maze0.bmp (0,0) (319,239) 65 120 (254,243,90) (0,0,0) (11,33,44)
```

I want to get the maze0.bmp and all the numbers. I have:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-z][^\\s]*)\\s+\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\)\\s+\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\((\\d+),(\\d+),(\\d+)\\)\\s*)"); 
BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( System.in));
String input;
Matcher matcher = null; 
boolean isMatched = false; 
while (!isMatched) {
    System.out.println("Please enter right format\n");
    input = stdin.readLine(); 
    matcher = pattern.matcher(input); 
    while(matcher.find()) {
        isMatched = true; 
        for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); ++i) 
            System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

but it's correct. For example, if my input is

```
Maze0.bmp (0,0) (319,239) 65 120 (254,243,90) (0,0,0)
```

it cannot get the the last tuple( 0,0,0).

Comment: Are you saying you only have tuples? If so, you can do a global match on (\\d+) and it should flatten them all out.

Comment: no. please read the question again. I just edited. stackoverflow changes the \\ to \ Thank you

Comment: You are aware that `[A-z]` typically matches non-letter characters (e.g., `[`, `^` and `_`) as well? There's a gap between `Z` and `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the best I can come up with. Note, that I used TWO patterns, because for some reason Java refuses to capture repeating groups (if anyone happens to know why, plz leave a comment).

```
final Pattern outerPattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?) \\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\) \\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\) (\\d+) (\\d+)(.*)");
final Pattern optionalTouplePattern = Pattern.compile(" \\((\\d+),(\\d+),(\\d+)\\)");

final BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
boolean isMatched;

do
{
    System.out.println("Please enter right format:");
    Matcher m = outerPattern.matcher(stdin.readLine());
    if (isMatched = m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(String.format("name='%s', first touple: [%s,%s], second touple: [%s,%s], first single number: %s, second single number: %s", m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3), m.group(4), m.group(5), m.group(6), m.group(7)));
        m = optionalTouplePattern.matcher(m.group(8));
        while(m.find())
        {
            System.out.println(String.format("+ optional touple: [%s,%s,%s]", m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3)));
        }
    }
}while(!isMatched);
```

Comment: `.. some reason Java refuses to capture repeating groups` This has nothing to do with Java. Regular expression capture groups retain the last item it captures. So `'aabbb' =~ /(a)+(b)+/ ` captures a and b respectively.

Comment: @sin: In PCRE you can get all repeated groups as well. Is this a special feature of PCRE that is non standard? (Can you quote an RFC or something similiar that states that what java does is the expected standard behaviour?) Thanks.

Comment: @yankee - Its a possible  misunderstanding of grouping behavior. There is only a single capture group that can be backreferenced, therefore, its contents at any given time must be referencable. A group will contain the value of the atomic expression it encapsulates and nothing more, ever, past its closing brace. So `'00aaabbb00' =~ / ((a)+(b)+) /` group 1 = 'aaabbb', 2 = 'a', 3 = 'b'.  Sound good?

Comment: @sin: Yes, I understand the design. But using the PCRE you can do somthing like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909830/php-split-string-into-2d-array/4909941#4909941 which works perfectly well and could be used here to parse the text with only one pattern. I understand the concept you described but the other concept is good in some cases, too (such as this one). And I wonder if one of the concepts has some kind of standard (or both). Or if it is eaven possible to set a flag in Java to get the same behaviour as in the linked script using PCRE.

Comment: @yankee No you misunderstand. @array = 'a-b-c a-b-c a-b-c a-b-c' =~ /(a)-(b)-(c)/g; @array is now equal to (a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c) ... All matched capture buffers accumulate into the array, has nothing to do with it. What you don't understand is the repeatability of anchors, in this case a-b-c is a complete match, a single record. You can't just do a (a)+ inside a RECORD and expect to get 'aaa' ... Btw, PCRE is based on Perl 5.8

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry, I have got to revise. The java matcher seems to not like pattern counts it can't determine at compile time of the regex. But this works (tested):

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\((\\d+),(\\d+),(\\d+)\\)").matcher("(23,56,78) (54,22,11)");
while(m.find())
{
  for(int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); ++i)
  System.out.println(m.group(i));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. why there's ? and :

Comment: plain parentheses create a sub pattern AND a group at the same time. I want the sub pattern (so that I can use a quantifier on it), but I don't care about making it a group. So I add ?: to the beginning which suppresses the group part.

Comment: I use Matcher to match the input and try to get the numbers by using the group(int index) function, but I can only get the number of the last tuple .For example if my input is (23,56,78) (54,22,11) I can only get 54 22 and 11 Don't know how to solve this.

Comment: that's probably because I forgot about the whitespaces in your groups. Hold on, I edit...

Comment: still only get the last tuple. Thank you though

Comment: sorry... Revised again. Now it should REALLY do.

Comment: Thank you.actually i read the input from console and matcher the input but if my input is more than 1 tuple, it doesn't match

Comment: I really tested the example above and at prints out six number (and the correct ones). So it should work for you as well. If it does not, you probably have something different. How do you read the string? Can copy the source somewhere?

Comment: Pattern pattern=
    Pattern.compile
    ("\\\((\\d+),(\\d+),(\\d+)\\\)");
 
   BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader  (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 
   
   String input;
   Matcher matcher = null;
   boolean isMatched = false;
   while(!isMatched){
    System.out.println("Please enter right format\n");
    input=stdin.readLine();
    matcher=pattern.matcher(input);
    isMatched = matcher.matches();
   }    for(int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); ++i)
    System.out.println(matcher.group(i));

Comment: now you go: `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((\\d+),(\\d+),(\\d+)\\)");
  BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    System.in));
  String input;
  Matcher matcher = null;
  boolean isMatched = false;
  while (!isMatched)
  {
   System.out.println("Please enter right format\n");
   input = stdin.readLine();
   matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
   while(matcher.find())
   {
    isMatched = true;
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); ++i)
     System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
   }
  }`

Comment: Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-z][^\\s]*)\\s+\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\)\\s+\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\)\\s+" +
      "(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+\\((\\d+),(\\d+),(\\d+)\\)"); 
 BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( System.in));
 String input;
 Matcher matcher = null; 
 boolean isMatched = false; 
 while (!isMatched) 
 { System.out.println("Please enter right format\n");
 input = stdin.readLine(); 
 matcher = pattern.matcher(input); 
 while(matcher.find()) 
 { isMatched = true; 
 for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); ++i) 
  System.out.println(matcher.group(i)); } }

 }

Comment: only get the first tuple .my input is Maze0.bmp (0,0) (319,239) 65 120 (254,243,90) (0,0,0)

Comment: Well yes, the regex I made is for only parantheses with 3 values. Now you have some with 2 and some without parantheses.

Comment: so I should ask user to enter twice?

Comment: Well... There are solutions for that. I may try again. Tomorrow. Because I am reeeeaaallly tired now. I kindly ask you edit your question in the mean time. Add several examples of different patterns that you want to be matched.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the context of matching in java, but I know regex very well.
Try this context:

```
while matching BITMAP records is not done
  ("
     ([A-z][^\s])            'maze.bmp'   ~ group 1
     \s+
     \(  (\d+),(\d+)  \)     '0' '0'      ~ group 2,3
     \s+
     \( (\d+),(\d+) \)       '319'  '239' ~ group 4,5
     \s+
     (\d+)                   '65'         ~ group 6
     \s+
     (\d+)                   '120'        ~ group 7
     \s+
     (
       (?: \( \d+,\d+,\d+ \) \s+ )+       '(254,243,90) (0,0,0) '     ~ group 8
     )
  ") - context = global
{
      // save to BITMAP.array (groups 1 - 7)
      copy group 8 to variable '(254,243,90) (0,0,0) '
      new matching of TUPLES, group 8 is the regex subject for this new match
         ("
            (\d+)
         ") - context = global

      append TUPLES.array (254 243 90 0 0 0)
      to BITMAP.array (maze.bmp 0 0 319 239 65 120 <append> 254 243 90 0 0 0)

     // do next BITMAP record
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't quiet understand this.

Comment: You don't understand what exactly?  Ask yankee, he understood it, see his code.